# Xenomai 3.1 mercury prologue failed for thread running official demo

Tags: linux, xenomai

Hello I have the following problem running a Xenomai demo: "prologue failed for thread" EINVAL

```
    debian:~/xenomai_mercury_lib/demo$ sudo ./alchemy/altency
    0"000.665| WARNING: [main] prologue failed for thread <anonymous>, EINVAL 
    == Sampling period: 100 us 
    == Test mode: periodic user-mode task 
    == All results in microseconds    
    0"000.997| WARNING: [main] prologue failed for thread alt-display-2077, EINVAL
    altency: failed to create display task, code -22
```

What I have:

- debian 10.10.0-amd64, installed inside a VirtualBox
- xenomai 3.1 mercury installed and built for 32bit target

xenomai configure:

```
../xenomai-3.1/configure --enable-lores-clock --with-core=mercury --enable-smp --enable-pshared CFLAGS="-m32 -O2" LDFLAGS="-m32"
```

Maybe something is missing inside the underlying OS? Something to install?

Do you have some ideas?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Easier with a 32bits OS. My xenomai-3.1 results from `Debian 10.9 - i386` https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/12jWKWIfvZz9wnD4pG4BkLAffttajZ0--?usp=sharing

Comment: Using a native 32 OS worked. Thanks for the tip!